# Facebook referrer - my FB page or someone else sharing my web page

Tags: facebook, utm-parameters

I have a FB page with FB posts.  Each posts contains a link to one of my website articles.  On my website, I also have links on my blog articles to allow a user to "Like/Share" the article.

So, a user might find my content on the web and Like/Share a page directly from my website.  They also might find my content on FB and share it from there.

I would like to know from which source FB referrals are coming - users who found my content on FB or users who share my content off my website and their friends read the shared content.

Assume there's no paid advertising.  If I manually add a UTM parameter to the "Like/Share" button on my website, would that be something that would survive the sharing process and allow me to identify at least sources that start with my webpage?

Comment: That's what the UTM parameters are for.  You can just make your own.  It becomes part of the posted/shared URL.

Comment: @RohitGupta, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652041/how-to-pass-a-parameter-like-title-summary-and-image-in-a-facebook-sharer-url, FB removes any querystring parameters.  Does it leave the UTM parameters?